# Last function code of 8puzzle in Python

Tags: python, matrix, sliding-tile-puzzle

```
def result(matrix):
        matrix2=matrix
        for a in possible_moves(matrix2):
            matrix2=matrix
            print()
            liste=swap_blank_tile(matrix2,a)
            print(liste)
            print(matrix)
```

I have this code in Python. Swap_blank_tile function creates a new matrix from old matrix. 
I want to put a value to "liste" from my first matrix. Therefore I used matrix2 in "swap_blank_tile" function, but "matrix" also is affected from "swap_blank_tile" function but i do not want it. Only matrix2 must be affected from this function. I can not solve why matrix is also affected from this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when:

```
matrix2=matrix
```

`matrix2` and `matrix` are still references to the same object, so if you change one you'll change the other. You'll probably want to create a deepcopy.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def result(matrix):
    matrix2=deepcopy(matrix)
    for a in possible_moves(matrix2):
        matrix2=deepcopy(matrix)
        print()
        liste=swap_blank_tile(matrix2,a)
        print(liste)
        print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

What data type is `matrix`?

Possibly it is a list of lists, in which case you need to make a complete copy of matrix. Use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy
matrix2 = deepcopy(matrix)
```

The reason for this is that `matrix2 = matrix` does not make a copy of `matrix`, it simply binds the name `matrix2` to the same object. Therefore any change made to the object is visible from both variables. `deepcopy()` will descend into the object and make a copy of any nested objects resulting in 2 independent objects.